# Python: Numpy Data IO, how to save data by different dtype for each column?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy.savetxt to dump data in to varieties of format for each column.

when data is

```
data = np.array([[1.111, 2.222, 3.333],
                 [4.444, 5.555, 6.666],
                 [7.777, 8.888, 9.999] ])
np.savetxt('data.txt', data, 
           fmt= ['%i', '%.2f', '%s'], ## <== 1st column, int, 2nd float, 3rd string
           delimiter = ',')
```

everything works fine.
But when data is:

```
data = np.array([[1.111, 2.222, 'three'],
                 [4.444, 5.555, 'six'],
                 [7.777, 8.888, 'nine'] ])

np.savetxt('data.txt', data, 
           fmt= ['%i', '%.2f', '%s'], ## <== 1st column, int, 2nd float, 3rd string
           delimiter = ',')
```

it gives me a error that:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
    TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.string_

Anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the array that you have created it looks like this:

```
array([['1.111', '2.222', 'three'],
   ['4.444', '5.555', 'six'],
   ['7.777', '8.888', 'nine']], 
  dtype='<U5')
```

As you can see all elements are strings and that is why you get that error.
However, if you do something like this, it should work.

```
dt = np.dtype("f, f, U5")
data = np.array([(1.111, 2.222, 'three'), # notice that each row had to be a tuple in my case
             (4.444, 5.555, 'six'),
             (7.777, 8.888, 'nine')], dtype=dt)
np.savetxt('data.txt', data, 
           fmt= ['%i', '%.2f', '%s'], ## <== 1st column, int, 2nd float, 3rd string
           delimiter = ',')
```

More info about dtypes are here:
[Data Type Objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: what does "dtype = '<U5' " means? where you got this definition? In addtion, by the way, the first two columns is all float, not string.

Comment: Nice! I think I didn't define the data type for each column in advance. And the data in the array are not tuple. I think that's why.

Comment: '<' indicates the byte order. 'U' mean unicode characters. '5' means 5 unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

For integer the **`%d`** format option should be used instead of **`%i`**:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', data, fmt=['%d', '%.2f', '%s'])
```

When loading the array you should also specify `dtype` properly:

```
np.genfromtxt('test.txt', dtype=[('col1', int), ('col2', float), ('col3', '|S8')])
```

Comment: np.savetxt(fname3, data3, fmt= ['%i', '%.2f', '%s'], delimiter = ','), it doens't work... but thank you.

Comment: @MacSanhe it was a typo... the right is `['%d', '%.2f', '%s']`... I've updated the answer...