# With a NumPy Unicode array, why does dtype '|U5' become dtype '<U5'?

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I learned from the comment in this answer [Python: Numpy Data IO, how to save data by different dtype for each column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248756/python-numpy-data-io-how-to-save-data-by-different-dtype-for-each-column/24249116)
that
< means byte order, U means unicode, and 5 means the number of characters.

Then what does '|' means in '|U5' and why did '|' change to '<' in the below example?
The example is from NumPy official documentation: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

```
data = u"1, abc , 2\n 3, xxx, 4"
# Without autostrip
np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=",", dtype="|U5")

array([['1', ' abc ', ' 2'],
       ['3', ' xxx', ' 4']], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: It's not significant.

Comment: @ddejohn The answer you suggested partially answers my first question. I appreciate for your suggestion. But I still wonder why | which means 'not applicable' changed to < (little endianness)

Comment: That's weird. It looks like NumPy is ignoring the `|`. `|` really shouldn't be valid for `U`.

Comment: @ddejohn, @richardec, @mozway: I agree with the OP: the question about why the `|` becomes `<` is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Warren sure fair point, but then maybe the title should be updated?

Comment: @mozway: agreed--how does the new title sound?

Comment: Perfect, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `U` data type stores each Unicode character as a 32 bit integer (i.e. 4 bytes).  An integer with more than one byte must have an endianess, so the data type will show either `<` or `>`.  Arrays of type `S` store each character in a single byte, so endianess is irrelevant, and the endianess character will be `|`.

For example, here `a1` and `a2` contain a single Unicode character.  The arrays are created with opposite endianess.

```
In [248]: a1 = np.array(['π'], dtype='<U1')

In [249]: a2 = np.array(['π'], dtype='>U1')

In [250]: a1
Out[250]: array(['π'], dtype='<U1')

In [251]: a2
Out[251]: array(['π'], dtype='>U1')
```

Inspect the actual bytes of the data in each array; you can see the different orders for each type:

```
In [252]: a1.view(np.uint8)
Out[252]: array([192,   3,   0,   0], dtype=uint8)

In [253]: a2.view(np.uint8)
Out[253]: array([  0,   0,   3, 192], dtype=uint8)
```

---

When you specify `|` with a Unicode type when creating an array, apparently NumPy ignores it and uses the native byte order, e.g.

```
In [254]: np.dtype("|U5")
Out[254]: dtype('<U5')
```

One might as well not include it at all:

```
In [255]: np.dtype("U5")
Out[255]: dtype('<U5')
```